# Vue.js watcher to duplicate inputs giving null reference

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I'm attempting to establish a watcher in Vue.js to duplicate an input conditionally. Using the value property, I keep experiencing null references, will someone elaborate to why this may be so I may better understand the issue?

My HTML:

```html
<div id="company-form">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input v-model="legalName" type="text"/>
    <label>Name To Call</label>
    <input v-model="communicationsName" />                      
</div>
```

My Vue code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#company-form',
    data: {
        legalName: null,
        communicationsName: null,
    },
    watch: {
        legalName: function() {
            if (!this.communicationsName.value || this.legalName.value == this.communicationsName.value) {
                this.communicationsName.value = this.legalName.value;                       
            }
         }
     },
});
```

Console Errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "legalName": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

vue.js:18 TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage) directive is used to create two-way data bindings.

Instead of doing `this.communicationsName.value` just do `this.communicationsName`.

The data property `communicationsName` already holds the value you are looking for, it is not an `HTMLInputElement` instance for it to have a `value` property.

Try the following:

```
watch: {
    legalName: function() {
        //Check to see if communicationsName's value is null or equal to legalName's value before duplicating input field text
        if (!this.communicationsName || this.legalName == this.communicationsName) {
            this.communicationsName = this.legalName;                       
        }
     }
 },
```

Note: The `if` condition `this.legalName == this.communicationsName` might not be necessary. The data properties already have the same value.

Comment: You could show a warning to let the user know the values are different and let them decide if that is okay or they fix it. I will update the answer, do not use `== null` in the `if` condition, we'll check for a falsy value instead. If you type into an input and then erase everything, the value will be an empty string and the condition will fail.

Answer (score 1):

> Use `Computed Properties` instead.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#company-form',
    data: {
        communicationsName: null,
    },
    computed: {
        legalName() {
           return this.communicationsName
         }
     },
});
```

You can tweak this code as per your use case.